# How to use aggregateField() over multiple columns in Apache Beam Java SDK?

Tags: java, apache-beam

In Apache Beam Python SDK, it is possible to perform the following:

```py
input
| GroupBy(account=lambda s: s["account"])
.aggregate_field(lambda x: x["wordsAddup"] - x["wordsSubtract"], sum, 'wordsRead')
```

How do we perform a similar action in the Java SDK? Strangely, the programming guide has [only examples in Python](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/groupby/) for this transform.

Here is my attempt at producing the equivalent in Java:

```
input.apply(
Group.byFieldNames("account")
.aggregateField(<INSERT EQUIVALENT HERE>, Sum.ofIntegers(), "wordsRead"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some Java examples at https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#using-schemas . (Note you may have to select the `java` tab on a selector that has both Java and Python to see them.)

In Java I don't think the first argument of aggregateField can take an arbitrary expression; it must be a field name. You can proceed the grouping operation with a projection that adds a new field for the desired expression.  For example

```
input
    .apply(SqlTransform.query(
        "SELECT *, wordsAddup - wordsSubtract AS wordsDiff from PCOLLECTION")
    .apply(Group.byFieldNames("account")
        .aggregateField("wordsDiff", Sum.ofIntegers(), "wordsRead"));
```

Comment: Thank you. Although that's the main page of the programming guide. There doesn't seem to be an equivalent separate page that goes specifically over thorough examples of the same transform per se, like there is for Python (see hyperlink in the question). I would appreciate if you could expand on what you mean by _"you can proceed the grouping operation with a projection that adds a new field for the desired expression."_ Do you mean a whole algorithm of PTransforms to get at the desired column? I will mark this as the correct answer if there is a code sample that performs the desired task.

Comment: Added an example, hopefully that helps.